# Eclipse showing variables in other objects

Tags: php, eclipse

I'm just starting to use Eclipse as my primary IDE but I'm kinda having problem in my Objects.

When I'm trying to access objects (typing `->`), the autosuggest shows all the variables in other objects. I declared all the variables and objects as `private` but no luck.

What should I do then?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear. I guess you are talking about c++ editor. Two comments:

- Autosuggest always shows all class members, and as far as I know there is no way to change this behavior. Autosuggest can't be modified to show only public members, but they are shown in different color. If autosuggest as such bothers you, it can be partially or completely turned off in Preferences -> c/c++ -> Editor -> Content assist.
- If you however by mistake try to access object members (where "object" is not actually pointer to object) using -> where you should have actually used . all other available variables are shown.

Comment: FYI: This question is about PHP.

Comment: Note to myself: check the tags! %-)